# Flutter bloc library

Tags: flutter, dart

Проблема с авторизацией юзера с блоком.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     home: MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => AuthBloc(authServiceTest: authServiceTest)
          ..add(AppStartedEvent()),
      ),
    ],
    child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is Authenticated) {
          return app(state.user);
        } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
          return HomeScreenTest();
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      }),
    ),
  ),
);
  }

  Widget app(FirebaseUser user) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('hello'),
    );
  }
}
```

Блок

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
 AuthServiceTest authServiceTest;
  AuthBloc({@required AuthServiceTest authServiceTest}) {
    this.authServiceTest = authServiceTest;
  }

  @override
  AuthState get initialState => AuthInitial();

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AppStartedEvent) {
      try {
        var isSignedin = await  authServiceTest.isSignedIn();
        if (isSignedin) {
          var user = await  authServiceTest.currentUser();
          yield Authenticated(user: user);
        } else {
          yield UnAuthenticated();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        yield UnAuthenticated();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

блок ивент

```
class AppStartedEvent extends AuthEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

блок стэйт

```
class Authenticated extends AuthState {
  final FirebaseUser user;

  Authenticated({@required this.user});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class UnAuthenticated extends AuthState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
```

все функции

```
class AuthServiceTest {

 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future registerUser(String email, String password) async {
    var authResult = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return authResult.user;
  }

  Future signIn(email, password) async {
    var authResult = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    return authResult.user;
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
  }

  Future<bool> isSignedIn() async {
    var currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    return currentUser != null;
  }

  Future currentUser() async {
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return user;
  }
}
```

Авторизация работает, после должен показывать виджет app, но не показывает. Либо проблемы в блоке с логикой или функции я прописал не правильно с получением юзера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как происходит авторизация вашего пользователя? Если при помощи вызова `AuthServiceTest.signIn(email, password)` то Ваш BloC не может отслеживать эти изменения, вам надо добавить в Bloc два дополнительных события:
SignIn & SignOut которые внутри блока будут вызывать соответсвующие методы из `AuthServiceTest`

Это будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

события

```dart
class AppStartedEvent extends AuthEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class SignInEvent extends AuthEvent {
 SignInEvent(this.email, this.password);
 final String email, password;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [email, password];
}

class SignOutEvent extends AuthEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

сам блок:

```dart
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc({@required this.authServiceTest})
 final AuthServiceTest authServiceTest;

  @override
  AuthState get initialState => AuthInitial();

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AppStartedEvent) {
      try {
        var isSignedin = await  authServiceTest.isSignedIn();
        if (isSignedin) {
          var user = await  authServiceTest.currentUser();
          yield Authenticated(user: user);
        } else {
          yield UnAuthenticated();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        yield UnAuthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is SignInEvent) {
      try {
        final user = await authServiceTest.signIn(event.email, event.password);
        yield Authenticated(user: user);
      } catch (error) {
        yield UnAuthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is SignOutEvent) {
      authServiceTest.signOut();
      yield UnAuthenticated();
    }

  }
}
```

После этого вызов `authBloc.add(SignInEvent(email, password))` и `authBloc.add(SignOutEvent())` будет приводить к соответствующим изменениям в состоянии блока и перерисовке UI, что в итоге при авторизации и отобразит ваш виджет app

Comment: я сделал все блоки отдельно, то есть на авторизацию на выход и вход. Каждый блок работал по отдельности, но как вы сказали изменения в состоянии блоки не видели. Могут ли разные блоки работать вместе?

Answer (score 0):

Писал по памяти возможно где-то нужно поправить. Метод `isSignedIn()` можно удалить.

```
Future currentUser() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
  return user;
}

...

@override
Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
  if (event is AppStartedEvent) {
    authServiceTest.isSignedIn().then((user){
      if (user.uid != null) {
        print("User: ${user.uid}");
        yield Authenticated(user: user);
      } else {
        print("User null");
        yield UnAuthenticated();
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("Error: ${e.error}");
      yield UnAuthenticated();
    });
  }
}
```

Если в консоль ничего не выведет значит проблема в этом `if (event is AppStartedEvent)`.